# CakePHP hasOne association conditions

Tags: cakephp

Hi I am building my User model to have only one profile picture, which is an example of an Image model. I want the conditions of the hasOne to only include the image where the Image.id is equal to the "picture" column in the user table. I know there is something wrong...here is the relevant part of code.

```
    var $hasOne = array(
            'ProfileImage' => array(
                    'className' => 'Image',
                    'conditions' => array('ProfileImage.id' => 'User.picture'),
                    'dependent' => false,
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            )
    );
```

What is wrong with my conditions? How do I specifc ProfileImage.id to be equal to the picture column in the User model? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If the foreign key (`picture`) is in the User model, then your association should be User belongsTo Image. If the image can only be used by one user at a time, the reverse would be Image hasOne user. If an image can be used by multiple users, it would be Image hasMany User.</strike>

But, if the image can only be used by one user at a time, the better data structure would be to add a `user_id` column to the `images` table. Then you have a User hasOne Image/Image belongsTo User relationship.

For neither you need `conditions`, only the `foreignKey`.

---

After your clarification of the issue, your condition needs to look like:

```
'conditions' => array('ProfileImage.id = User.picture')
```

Otherwise Cake thinks `ProfileImage.id` should equal the string `"User.picture"`.

Comment: so images belong to only one user. I already have Image belongs to User, and User hasMany pictures. I am adding a differently titled relationship for the special case where the Image is a profile picture (as referenced by the id in the User.picture column). Images table already has a user_id column.

Comment: ok so now I see in the SQL that it is no longer trying to equal it to the string "User.picture", like you rightly pointed out. But now the queries are not doing a LEFT join at all, so it is not recognizing the field User.picture

Comment: How are you querying for that and what is the generated SQL? `hasOne` associations *should* be included in the primary query for the User model automatically...

Comment: i am purposely altering the name of one of fields to create an error so it shows me what the SQL says. the error is like: Unknown column 'User.picture' in 'where clause'